# Связь один ко многим mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, связывание-данных

Есть 2 таблицы в mysql. Связь один ко многим(Один продукт у него несколько описаний).Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос который будет выводить по id товара все описания  товара из др таблицы.

Comment: использовать обычный inner join этих двух таблиц

Comment: и на самом деле даже это ван не нужно. если нужны все описания по id товара то делаете просто select из таблицы с описаниями по id товара, а таблица продуктов не нужна в запросе

Comment: Тут даже join не нужен потому что привязка скорее всего идет по product_id

Answer (score 1):

У тебя есть две таблицы (таблица с продуктами - products_table, где у каждого продукта есть уникальное поле ID, и таблица с описаниями - description_table, где есть поле productID - номер продукта, которому принадлежит описание, и desc - собственно само описание)

```
SELECT 
    description_table.desc, 
    products_table.ID
FROM  
    products_table, description_table 
WHERE
    description_table.productID = products_table.ID
```